# Dplyr get paired columns (foo.x, foo.y) difference

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to get the difference of many `foo.x` and `foo.y` columns all in one mutate across. Here is an example dataframe.

```
mydf <- tibble(ID = 1:5,
               foo1.x = c(9, 8, 3, 2, 10),
               foo1.y = c(4, 5, 3, 2, 4),
               foo2.x = c(8, 5,10, 11, 6),
               foo2.y = c(10, 6,4, 8, 5),
               foo3.x = c(15, 12, 5, 45, 1),
               foo3.y = c(5, 8, 2, 6, 4))
```

I want to do `foo.x - foo.y` like the code below, but get `non-numeric argument to binary operator` error although the columns are all of type num in `str(df)`

```
df <- mydf %>%        
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), ~. -~eval(
   as.name(paste0(substring(toString(cur_column()),1,
    str_length(toString(cur_column()))-2),".y")))))
```

Thanks

Comment: I made a [package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67232095/dplyr-get-paired-columns-foo-x-foo-y-difference) that extends the functionality of `dplyr::across` to loop over paired columns. There is also [vignette](https://timteafan.github.io/dplyover/articles/why_dplyover.html) which compares different approaches, so it might not be necessary to use the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the (foo.x,foo.y) difference

```
Difference <- mydf %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with('.x'), 
  ~(. - get(str_replace(cur_column(), ".x$", ".y")))))
```